# d3.js - filtering the data for stacked charts

Tags: d3.js

I want to filter the records from csv for creating the stacked chart. I am using the columns "open defect" and "total" to be stacked for a component.

```
//now read from the csv file. the param being criteriamap 
d3.csv("data_src/CompOpenDefect.csv", function(criteriamap) 
{



    // Transpose the data into layers by codecoverage/defects.We call it tasks.
    var tasks = d3.layout.stack()(["open", "total"].map(function(cause) 
    {
            return criteriamap.map(function(d) 
        {
            return {x:d.Component, y: +d[cause]};
        });
  }));


});
```

this is returning all the rows in the csv. I want to filter the records.

I used the following to filter(temp variable) but it did not work. I tried putting inside the d3.csv function call and vice-versa

```
d3.text("data_src/CompOpenDefect.csv", function(datasetText) 
            {
                parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);
                filteredData= parsedCSV.filter(function(row) 
                    {

                            return row[0] == temp 

                    })




            });
```

the csv data is:

```
Component,open,total,Week
Mastersaf DF-e - Integration,10,50,Week1
Unified Admin Portal Web Service - Integration,3,5,Week1
Mastersaf DF-e - Messaging,3,5,Week1
```

Comment: How does it not work? What is the value of `temp`?

Comment: The temp value is the filter value viz "Unified Admin Portal Web Service". I would like to get the rows for the records which matches the component i.e component name column.

Comment: In your CSV it says "Unified Admin Portal Web Service - Integration". Did you want to match on that?

Comment: Well that's not the same as "Unified Admin Portal Web Service".

Comment: my apologies, i missed the "-Integration". I would be selecting and assigning the value in the temp. Based on the value on temp i need to filter the records and then carry on with the stack chart for the selected rows.

Comment: So if your value is "Unified Admin Portal Web Service - Integration", does it retain the value you want?

Comment: yes, the value is retained.

Comment: So it works as intended?

Comment: the records are not getting filtered.... i am not sure where to put the code... i tried putting immediately before the var tasks = d3.layout.stack()... it did not work

Comment: You would use `filteredData` instead of `parsedCSV`.

Comment: i need to write like this:filteredData= filteredData.filter(function(row)

Comment: I found the issue. the variable temp was a string and i was comparing it with the row object. I changed the code to row.Component == temp and the filter worked. Thank you Lars Kotthoff for your comments.It helped me to debug further and reach the solution.